# Date difference between two dates with format 01/06/18

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi ALL I am trying to get date difference between two dates. I am getting data from cube and saving in temp table. I tried to defined date field as a varchar and also datetime and date 
My date is in the format 03/04/18 
And I am trying `DATEDIFF(DAY, PAAR.DateReceived, O.DateReceived)` for getting number of days difference. But I am getting error as below.

When I defined date field in temp table as DateTime or Date 
"Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with datetime"
When I defined date field in temp table as Varchar then
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I don't know what ntext is, but ehy not start with properly formatted dates?

Comment: Hi Because of date format in the cube. It is storing date as 01/12/19. And I am fetching data from cube and storing in the temp table. And in the temp table I tried with both varchar and date format.

Comment: Dates should always be (real) dates, and that format is rubbish as well, it is ambiguous! e.g. is `01` the day of month, or the month?  YYYY-MM-DD is not ambiguous

Comment: I can't tell from your date examples if your using DD/MM/YY (little endian) or MM/DD/YY (US wonky date format).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
set @sdate = '01/01/18';
set @edate = '01/26/18';

set @sdate = CONCAT_WS('-',SUBSTR(@sdate FROM 7 FOR 2),SUBSTR(@sdate FROM 1 FOR 2),SUBSTR(@sdate FROM 4 FOR 2));
set @edate = CONCAT_WS('-',SUBSTR(@edate FROM 7 FOR 2),SUBSTR(@edate FROM 1 FOR 2),SUBSTR(@edate FROM 4 FOR 2));

SELECT DATEDIFF(date(@edate), date(@sdate));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I did bit modification as below "CONCAT(RIGHT(@dt,2),'-',SUBSTRING(@dt,4,2),'-',LEFT(@dt,2))" And it woek

Comment: string manipulation is a bit ghastly compared to built in functions like the `str_to_date` answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `str_to_date()` with the appropriate format modifiers to convert those strings into dates.

```
DATEDIFF(str_to_date(PAAR.DateReceived,'%d/%m/%y'), str_to_date(O.DateReceived,'%d/%m/%y'))
```

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date